# create alert policy with Cloud Function and Python - positional arguments error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to create a new alert policy using the monitoring v3 API. I'm following this  [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/0.31.1/gapic/v3/api.html)

I have this cloud function:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import json

client = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicyServiceClient()

alert_policy = {
        "displayName": "This is a test",
        "combiner": "OR",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "displayName": "This is a test",
                "conditionAbsent": {
                    "duration": "3900s",
                    filter: "resource.type = \"l7_lb_rule\" AND metric.type = \"logging.googleapis.com/user/metric_name_here\""
                }
            }
        ],
    }

    
    name = 'projects/my-project'
    client.create_alert_policy(name, alert_policy)
```

When running the function for a test I have the log error  `TypeError: create_alert_policy() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

What do I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because of the changes made in 2.0 release of google-cloud-monitoring where required parameters are positional parameters. See [google cloud monitoring 2.0 change log](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/UPGRADING.html#more-details) for reference. To adapt to the changes, you should define the parameters in `create_alert_policy()` explicitly.

```
client.create_alert_policy(name=name, alert_policy=alert_policy)
```